# SizedBox is not occupying full width inside a Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So, I am making a Login Screen, but my SizedBox is not occupying the full width of the Screen, making it looks weird.

Follow my code:

```
return SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      right: false,
      left: false,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: currentThemeMode == ThemeMode.light
              ? myColor
              : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: const AssetImage("assets/images/background2.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
              Theme.of(context)
                  .colorScheme
                  .tertiary
                  .withOpacity(currentThemeMode == ThemeMode.light ? 0.5 : 0.5),
              BlendMode.dstATop,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 80,
                child: _buildTop(),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                child: _buildBottom(correctBigSpacing),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
Widget _buildBottom(bigSpacing) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: mediaSize.width,
      child: Card(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
          child: _buildForm(bigSpacing),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xera3.png)

I tried to put the SizedBox out of the Container as a test, as unique child, and it worked full width. However I need it inside the Container.

Comment: What is mediaSize?  Why not width: double.infinity, which will make it as large as the parent permits?

Comment: As an aside, what you are doing with the `Stack` could be more idiomatically done with a `Column`. Make the first child have a fixed height of 80 (by putting it in a `SizedBox` or something) and then wrap the second child in an `Expanded` or `Flexible`.

Comment: If I change the SizedBox to double.infinity it fades away, tried that

Comment: @Abion47 But there is a Image in background, and this sizedbox comes above it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Card` widgets have a default non-zero margin.

To fix it:

```
Widget _buildBottom(bigSpacing) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: mediaSize.width,
    child: Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero, // ADD THIS LINE
      ...
    ),
  );
}
```

I recommend always checking the default parameters for the widgets that you are using to prevent any unwanted UI.